# Convert dxf to JSON will ignore few records like "INDEX"

Tags: javascript, json, 2d

When I convert the dxf file to JSON through dxf-parser it was ignoring few data like "INDEX" with value.

Help me to find out the solution for this.

If required more information please ping me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found the answer that the dxf-parser package ignore few values.

As dxf files are working with code as like how we define any variable with name in coding the same way dxf file was defined variable name with numbercode in dxf file.

It was creating new object of an array when found "0" code as it was defined to create new object. As I have question that it was ignoring my index value i have update the dxf-parser package file to manage add my index value as i am using " ATTRIB " entity type as child of INSERT type.

As on dxf-parser package it was not predefined for entity type " ATTRIB ".